# Does anyone have experience using the Affirma ThreeSharp library on a 64 bit machine?

Tags: c#, 64-bit, amazon-s3

I have been developing and testing the ThreeSharp library on a 32bit Vista machine with no problems. However, when I deploy to a 64 bit machine the application will start ok then dramatically slow down after about 1 minute and terminate without any message. When I look into the logs I see "Application Error, faulting module KERNEL32.dll" followed by some hexadecimal data.

Is there something I can do to have this excellent library work on my 64 bit Windows server? Any helpful pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that it was a threading issue. ThreeSharp does work on 64 bit machines! Something perhaps also to do with my developer machine having two cores and the server having four cores. Using the ThreadPool class seems to have fixed this.